# converting T-sql to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql

i have a T-sql code that i run on SQL server successfully.

```
SELECT
(SELECT
    Address
FROM
    customer_address
WHERE
    ProspectID = tm.ProspectID
    AND TYPE = 'RESIDENCE') AS Residence_Address
 FROM
    landing.kp_los_trx_master tm
INNER JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_status ts ON
    tm.ProspectID = ts.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_confins_branch cb ON
    tm.BranchID = cb.BranchID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_personal cp ON
    tm.ProspectID = cp.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_items ti ON
    tm.ProspectID = ti.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_apk ta ON
    tm.ProspectID = ta.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_employment cem ON
    tm.ProspectID = cem.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_emcon ce ON
    tm.ProspectID = ce.ProspectID
```

But, when i want to convert its code to postgresql with the code i created shown below;

```
SELECT
(SELECT
        a.address 
    FROM
        landing.kp_los_customer_address a 
        inner join landing.kp_los_trx_master b on
        a.ProspectID = b.ProspectID
        where a."Type" = 'RESIDENCE') AS Residence_Address
FROM
    landing.kp_los_trx_master tm
INNER JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_status ts ON
    tm.ProspectID = ts.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_confins_branch cb ON
    tm.BranchID = cb.BranchID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_personal cp ON
    tm.ProspectID = cp.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_items ti ON
    tm.ProspectID = ti.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_trx_apk ta ON
    tm.ProspectID = ta.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_employment cem ON
    tm.ProspectID = cem.ProspectID
LEFT JOIN landing.kp_los_customer_emcon ce ON
    tm.ProspectID = ce.ProspectID
```

the result is getting error that:

```
SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

i dont know how to solve of its code, anyone have any idea to help me?
thank in advance

Comment: Your original code should run in Postgres.

Comment: You've removed the correlated join in your sub query. Also *why* all those `LEFT JOIN`s when the only object you define in the `FROM` (in the T-SQL) that you use in the query is `kp_los_trx_master`. In the PostgreSQL you don't reference a single one of the objects in the `FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code should run in Postgres -- or in fact in any database.

However, when using correlated subqueries you should always qualify *all* column references to be sure they are referring to exactly what you intend:

```
SELECT (SELECT ca.Address
        FROM customer_address ca
        WHERE ca.ProspectID = tm.ProspectID AND
              ca.TYPE = 'RESIDENCE'
       ) AS Residence_Address
```

Qualifying column references is generally a good idea, but even more strongly recommended with subqueries.

Note:  I would also suggest that you avoid double quotes around column and table names, so you can avoid double quotes in queries.